# how to test whether Struts 1.1 classLoader manipulation fix is working?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, struts1

I'm using Struts 1.3.10 with Websphere 8. This is related to the recently identified [class loader vulnerability](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-021.html) in Struts 1 & 2 frameworks. I was trying to implement a fix recoginised by Apache org as correct. [This is the fix that I applied in my application](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-Security-Research-Blog/Protect-your-Struts1-applications/ba-p/6463188#.U2J7xeaSxro)

I tried testing the fix by providing urls with parameters like
 "?class.classLoader.defaultAssertionStatus=true", 
or "class.classLoader.resource.dircontext.docBase=someText" either case all such urls  are permitted into my application. I see those urls inside the finalParameters returned by the by getParameters(). Am I testing correctly or am I missing something here?

Thanks.